# What kind of bandwidth / availability is provided by Polkadot's Erasure Encoding within the Parachains Protocol?

Tags: parachain-system

During the Polkadot Blockchain Academy in Buenos Aries, there were some metrics noted on the bandwidth / availability provided by the Parachains Protocol through Erasure Encoding.

What were those metrics, and how do they compare to other data availability protocols in the present day blockchain space?

For example, I would like to know something like:

- Polkadot provides availability of X MB of data across it's validators.
- The protocol transfers X MB of data on average per parachain block.
- This is compares to <other protocol>, which has...

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial answer back in the slides:

```
Comparison with other approaches

    - Both Danksharding and Celestia use 2D encoding and DAS
    - Celestia doesn't implement data sharding
    - Data availability is only part of ensuring validity
    - Polkadot's DA is able to process dozens of MB per second
```

In the speaker notes:

```
Danksharding is aiming at 1.3 MB/s and Celestia < 1 MB/s.
```